# Is there a possibility to sort dojox.calendar events in columns within the column?

Tags: calendar, dojo

I have about 10 to 15 calendars I want to show in a single day ColumnView. To see free room for more events I want each calendar to have it's own column within the column view. I set the overlap to 0, but all events of one calendar need to be in the same column.

Looking at the [demo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/calendar/demo.html) I want to have all red events on the left side of the column and all blue events on the right side.

Is there a possibility to do this or is it easier to create multiple calendar-widgets for the specific calendars?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, the absolute solution would be to manage multiple columns per day which is not implemented by the dojox.calendar yet.

Feel free to register a feature wish on the github page: https://github.com/damiengarbarino/dojo-calendar in the Issues section.

With that said, you can change the layout priority of events see: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#layout-priority

Set a custom priory function that takes into account the calendar of a data item to column view layoutPriorityFunction property.
This is a sorting function, so it takes 2 items to compare and return 0 (not useful here), -1 or 1.

Hope this helps,

Damien